# Backbone collection export issues

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a collection of users (model user)
model has a boolean value: isExport
i have a button that on click supposed to post to the server all the users that isExport=true
Can anyone suggest a suitable solution for this problem?

I know it's possible to wrap the collection as a model and overwrite the toJSON function
but couldn't manage it so far (can someone please give a code example?)

```
App.User = Backbone.Model.extend({ defaults: {isExport: false}...});
App.Users = Backbone.Collections.extend({model: App.User...});
```

Thanks!
Roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone collections by default don't have any write operations to the server, so you'll need to add a new method to your Collection subclass such as `doExport`, use `.where` to get the models with `isExport=true` and their `toJSON()` to get an array of objects which you can then send to the server with `Backbone.sync` or `$.post`.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone comes with RESTful support.
So, if you give each collection a url pointing to the collection rest service, then with a few functions (create,save) you can handle server requests.

```
App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend();
App.Collections.Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'users',
    model: App.Models.User
});
```

So, this way, you can:

```
var users = new App.Collections.Users();
users.fetch(); // This will call yoursite.com/users
               // Expecting a json request
```

And then you can:

```
users.create({ name: 'John', isExport: true });
```

This will send a post request to the server, in order to create a new record.
And you can check on server side if it has the flag you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
App.Views.ExportAll = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#exportAll',


events: {
    'click': 'exportAll'
},

exportAll: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('exporting all');
    console.log(this.collection.toJSON());

    var exportModel = new App.Models.Export;
    exportModel.set("data", this.collection.toJSON());
    console.log(exportModel.toJSON());
    exportModel.save();
}
});
```

I think this is the best solution for the problem